# Как загрузить файл с компьютера на web-сервер контроллера?

Tags: qt, веб-программирование, post, lighttpd

Имеется контроллер с web сервером lighttpd. На нем же развернута cgi программа на с++ с использованием qt, которая создает веб-интерфейс.
Необходимо сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог с браузера выбирать файл, и этот файл загружался в контроллер. Весь интернет уже перерыл, но везде в примерах программа развертывается на компе и передает данные на удаленный веб-сервер, а тут программа развернута на контроллере, из-за этого естественно ничего не работает. Единственное что нашел - возможно нужно использовать класс QHttpMultiPart, однако внятные примеры также отсутствуют.

Страница с выбором файла:

```html
<h2>Загрузка ПО</h2>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="cgi?downloadpost" method="post">
<fieldset><label> Укажите путь к загружаемому файлу <input name="g1" type="file"></label></fieldset><p>&nbsp;</p><p align=right><input type="submit" name="button" value="Загрузить" />
</p></form>
```

Comment: CGI все данные передает через cin, а файлы передаются методом POST соотвественно скрипт(программа) должны обработать POST запрос. Конечно лучше найти готовую либу, которая умеет текст запроса распарсить и разложить по переменным/методам.

Comment: Дак я понимаю, что через POST, но как конкретно вытащить из него архив. Если файл просто текстовый, тогда текст считать можно из Content-Type:. Но архив туда не передает ничего.

Comment: Про архив в вопросе не было ни слова, в обще файлы передаются в декодированном виде base64(url encoded). Соотвественно вам надо прочитать cin и загнать в декодер данные.